# About tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient

When I tried to achieve the example from the book of Deep Learning with Python by Tensorflow 2.0. I met an error that told me: RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.

```
def generate_pattern(layer_name, filter_index, size=150):
layer_output = model.get_layer(layer_name).output
loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])

grads = K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0]

grads /= (K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(grads))) + 1e-5)

iterate = K.function([model.input], [loss, grads])

input_img_data = np.random.random((1, size, size, 3)) * 20 + 128.

step = 1.
for i in range(40):
    loss_value, grads_value = iterate([input_img_data])
    input_img_data += grads_value * step

img = input_img_data[0]
return deprocess_image(img)
```

Comment: What's the issue? Did you read the [guide about the gradient tape](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff?hl=en)?

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, I found a way to avoid this problem. You only need to add the following code before the example to resolve it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```